# How to block locking(itself) device in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

I do not want to my Nokia Lumia 820 ever lock itself. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

The question seems too simple, so maybe there is a misunderstanding.

On my, older windows phone, I go to settings > lock+wallpaper > Screen times out after and there I can select never.

Answer (score 1):

I don't about Nokia, but on my Huawei Ascend W1 I just go to settings / lock screen and set `screen timeout after` to never.